# Trying to add Inventory Item (QBO) but properties are being ignored

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am using the IPP .NET SDK (ver 2.0.1.0), VS2013, and C#

My code to submit a new item is as follows (I've plugged in static data to verify).

```
var item = new Item()
{ 
    Type = ItemTypeEnum.Inventory,
    TrackQtyOnHand = true,
    QtyOnHand = 12,
    InvStartDate = DateTime.Today,
    Active = true,
    Name = "TEST0004",
    Description = "Test Product",
    PurchaseDesc = "Test Product",
    Taxable = true,
    SalesTaxIncluded = false,
    IncomeAccountRef = new ReferenceType() { Value = "1" }, // SALES
    ExpenseAccountRef = new ReferenceType() { Value = "50" }, // COGS
    AssetAccountRef = new ReferenceType() { Value = "49" }, // Inventory Asset
    UnitPrice = 10M,
    PurchaseCost = 7.5M,
    sparse = true
};

ServiceContext serviceContext = getServiceContext(profile);
var data = new DataService(serviceContext).Add<Item>(item);
```

My expectation is to havea new inventory item added with quantity tracking enabled. Below is the response I get when querying for this product using the API Explorer.

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2013-12-30T11:45:02.640-08:00">
  <QueryResponse startPosition="1" maxResults="1">
    <Item domain="QBO" sparse="false">
      <Id>21</Id>
      <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
      <MetaData>
        <CreateTime>2013-12-30T11:40:41-08:00</CreateTime>
        <LastUpdatedTime>2013-12-30T11:40:41-08:00</LastUpdatedTime>
      </MetaData>
      <Name>TEST0004</Name>
      <Description>Test Product</Description>
      <Active>true</Active>
      <FullyQualifiedName>TEST0004</FullyQualifiedName>
      <Taxable>false</Taxable>
      <UnitPrice>0</UnitPrice>
      <Type>Service</Type>
      <IncomeAccountRef name="Sales">1</IncomeAccountRef>
      <PurchaseDesc>Test Product</PurchaseDesc>
      <PurchaseCost>0</PurchaseCost>
      <ExpenseAccountRef name="Cost of Goods Sold">50</ExpenseAccountRef>
      <TrackQtyOnHand>false</TrackQtyOnHand>
    </Item>
  </QueryResponse>
</IntuitResponse>
```

The most critical problems I'm encountering are:
1. The item gets added as a Service type not Inventory
2. The TrackQtyOnHand is false, not true
3. The AssetAccountRef is missing,
4. The initial QtyOnHand  is missin,
5. The PurchaseCost and UnitPrice are 0

What's going on? Is this SDK broken? Or am I missing something. I've been able to get very similar code working for locations (departments), categories (classes).

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have enabled "QtyOnHand" from QBO's Preference menu.

I've tried this from APIExplorer. It works fine there. Please have a look.

**Create Request**

```
<Item xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" sparse="false">
      <Name>ABCD_CLONE</Name>
      <Active>true</Active>
      <FullyQualifiedName>ABCD</FullyQualifiedName>
      <Taxable>false</Taxable>
      <UnitPrice>45</UnitPrice>
      <Type>Inventory</Type>
      <IncomeAccountRef name="Sales of Product Income">49</IncomeAccountRef>
      <PurchaseCost>0</PurchaseCost>
      <ExpenseAccountRef name="Cost of Goods Sold">50</ExpenseAccountRef>
      <AssetAccountRef name="Inventory Asset">51</AssetAccountRef>
      <TrackQtyOnHand>true</TrackQtyOnHand>
      <QtyOnHand>1000</QtyOnHand>
      <InvStartDate>2013-12-31</InvStartDate>
</Item>
```

**Response**

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2013-12-30T19:42:45.781-08:00">
  <Item domain="QBO" sparse="false">
    <Id>6</Id>
    <SyncToken>0</SyncToken>
    <MetaData>
      <CreateTime>2013-12-30T19:42:45-08:00</CreateTime>
      <LastUpdatedTime>2013-12-30T19:42:45-08:00</LastUpdatedTime>
    </MetaData>
    <Name>ABCD_CLONE</Name>
    <Active>true</Active>
    <FullyQualifiedName>ABCD_CLONE</FullyQualifiedName>
    <Taxable>false</Taxable>
    <UnitPrice>45</UnitPrice>
    <Type>Inventory</Type>
    <IncomeAccountRef name="Sales of Product Income">49</IncomeAccountRef>
    <PurchaseCost>0</PurchaseCost>
    <ExpenseAccountRef name="Cost of Goods Sold">50</ExpenseAccountRef>
    <AssetAccountRef name="Inventory Asset">51</AssetAccountRef>
    <TrackQtyOnHand>true</TrackQtyOnHand>
    <QtyOnHand>1000</QtyOnHand>
    <InvStartDate>2013-12-31</InvStartDate>
  </Item>
</IntuitResponse>
```

If possible please grab the original request XML from code by configuring the logger in debug mode.

PN - There is an open bug related to QtyOnHand update. That is expected to be fixed in the next release.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The main reason that your C# code does not work is because Intuit requires that you set various "Is Specified" properties, such as TrackQtyOnHandSpecified = true.

Hopefully they will improve their property setting to automatically set these Specified fields to true when we assign data to them.  For now, you will need to look at each property you set to see if there is an associated Specified property to set at the same time.  Awkward for now.

Cheers,
Greg

Answer (score 0):

It seems they still didn't fix this issue. But here I am, I can tell u a workaround to fix this issue.

Just create a new Item as you usually do :

```
            Item i = new Item();
            i.Name = "Art 1";
            i.TrackQtyOnHand = true;
            i.TypeSpecified = true;
            i.Type = ItemTypeEnum.Inventory;
            i.QtyOnHand = 0;
            i.InvStartDate = DateTime.Now;
            i.PurchaseCost = 10;
            i.UnitPrice = 111;
            i.FullyQualifiedName = "Art 1";

            i.IncomeAccountRef = new ReferenceType
            {
                Value = "63"
            };
            i.ExpenseAccountRef = new ReferenceType
            {
                Value = "64"
            };
            i.AssetAccountRef = new ReferenceType
            {
                Value = "65",
                name = "Inventory Asset"

            };
            Item newItem = dataService.Add(i) as Item;
```

Now to fix this you must make immediately an update to the newly added product as so:

```
            newItem.UnitPrice = i.UnitPrice;
            newItem.PurchaseCost = i.PurchaseCost;
            newItem.QtyOnHand = i.QtyOnHand;
            newItem.InvStartDate = i.InvStartDate;
            newItem.Type = i.Type;
            newItem.TypeSpecified = true;
            newItem.AssetAccountRef = i.AssetAccountRef;
            i = dataService.Update(newItem) as Item;
```

And wala, that's it.
Hope it will be helpful to somebody ;)